# How to deactivate bash_history stats print when opening a new terminal window on my mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, macos-sierra, bash

I just reinstalled MacOS (OSX 10.12) and as I'm redoing my IDEs and such I get this strange bash_history stats object that prints to every new terminal window! It's driving me bonkers, and after looking through all the preferences an settings I can't seem to turn it off! Does anyone know why this is suddenly happening? Is it something to do with iCloud Profile Syncing? Here's s picture below. Thanks so much for your help!

[Screenshot of bash terminal history stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coFMk.png)

```
Last login: Wed Jul  5 03:23:51 on ttys005
/Users/admin/.bash_sessions/5D8EB886-1FE8-4DF6-AC4C-6ACE7B8CF803.historynew Stats {
dev: 16777220,
mode: 33152,
nlink: 1,
uid: 501,
gid: 20,
rdev: 0,
blksize: 4096,
ino: 1411298,
size: 0,
blocks: 0,
atime: 2017-07-05T10:24:18.000Z,
mtime: 2017-07-05T10:24:18.000Z,
ctime: 2017-07-05T10:24:18.000Z,
birthtime: 2017-07-05T10:24:18.000Z }
CafeMisto:~ admin$
```

so the **/etc/profile** is like this:

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
    eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
    [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

and the **/etc/bashrc** is like this:

```
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
   return
fi

PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
# Make bash check its window size after a process completes
shopt -s checkwinsize

[ -r "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM" ] && . "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM"
```

and I've checked my user/profile home folder and there's no .bashrc...

Comment: Check /etc/motd or /etc/profile

Comment: **so '/etc/profile' looks like this:** ``` # System-wide .profile for sh(1)
if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
        eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
        [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
``` 
**and the '/etc/bashrc' looks like this:**
```
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
   return
fi

PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
# Make bash check its window size after a process completes
shopt -s checkwinsize

[ -r "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM" ] && . "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM"
```

Comment: @MatthewWilkinson it's really tough to format things well in comments, and people won't necessarily find the information there.  Instead, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44923968/edit) the question with any updated info, like the contents of `/etc/profile` or the like

Comment: Also, oddly iterm2 and my platformioIDE (bash emulator inside atom) doesn't do this as well...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had the same problem, and have tracked it down to having the `touch` NPM/Node package installed globally on the system, which places an alternative `touch` command in your PATH.

`$ ls -l $(which touch)
lrwxr-xr-x  1 timshel  admin  74 18 Jul 12:47 /usr/local/bin/touch -> ../../../Users/timshel/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/touch/bin/touch.js`

(I've used `yarn global add` to install packages on my system rather than `npm install -g`)

On my system, a simple `$ rm /usr/local/bin/touch` fixed the issue (I think the `touch` NPM package got installed as a dependency on my system; it isn't even installed properly).

Also, the reason you only observed this in Apple Terminal is that the `touch` command which causes the Stat data to be printed is located in `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal`; which is only loaded in Apple Terminal by the following line in `/etc/bashrc`:

`[ -r "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM" ] && . "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM"`

`/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` isn't loaded in other terminal emulators (e.g. your platformioIDE example).

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the extended answer! 
This makes so much sense. 
And indeed I was using `yarn global add`... 
I know... I know...