# Bash printing unnecessary things on new session since MacOS update

Tags: bash, terminal, macos-sierra

The following line in `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal`

```
shell_session_history_enable() {
        (umask 077; touch "$SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE_NEW") <<< THIS LINE
        HISTFILE="$SHELL_SESSION_HISTFILE_NEW"
        SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=1
    }
```

is printing something like this on every new session.

```
/Users/me/.bash_sessions/717F6632-A946-44EE-8A27-2547EDDD09E9.historynew Stats {
  dev: 16777220,
  mode: 33152,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 501,
  gid: 20,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: 4096,
  ino: 1406878,
  size: 0,
  blocks: 0,
  atimeMs: 1502801769000,
  mtimeMs: 1502801769000,
  ctimeMs: 1502801769000,
  birthtimeMs: 1502801769000,
  atime: 2017-08-15T12:56:09.000Z,
  mtime: 2017-08-15T12:56:09.000Z,
  ctime: 2017-08-15T12:56:09.000Z,
  birthtime: 2017-08-15T12:56:09.000Z }
```

Closest thing as to when is since last MacOS update.

What's an elegant way to solve this without changing this file I don't really want to change?

Comment: If you manually start a new login shell, do you see this output? `bash -li` If yes, turn on tracing (`bash -lix`) to see what files are being sourced and what commands are being run. The line you highlighted does not emit any output (unless there's an alias/function/script called "touch" somewhere)

Comment: Thanks Glenn. I'm 100% sure that that's the line that printing. When I put echo 'hi' above and below the output is in between those two hi's. Plus, when I remove that line it stops the weird behaviour. I'll investigate further, as indeed it makes no sense that that line prints anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post answers my question

[How to deactivate bash_history stats print when opening a new terminal window on my mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44923968/how-to-deactivate-bash-history-stats-print-when-opening-a-new-terminal-window-on)

I didn't entertain the possibility that there was an alias for touch, but indeed this was the case.